# javascript , onclick i want from user enter valid name and age getting problems

Tags: javascript, validation

```
let userdetails = {};

document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function() {
  let username = prompt("enter name pleas")
  while (!isNaN(username)) {
    username = prompt("enter valid user name not numbers")
  }
  while (username.length < 3)
    username = prompt("enter valid name ")
  while (username.length > 8)
    username = prompt("enter valid name pleas between 1 to 8")


  let age = prompt("enter your age ")
  ageval = age.parseInt
  while (age < 16 || age > 100)
    age = prompt("enter valid age between 16 to 120")
  while (String(age))
    age = prompt("enter numbers")
```

I want if a user click's the onClick button, the user should get a prompt that asks for their name. The name is valid, if its between 1 - 8 characters in length and does not contain any numbers.

If the name is not valid, the user will get the prompt again "enter valid name , not numbers "

If the user does not enter a valid name, the user will get the prompt again till a valid name is entered and then stored in the userdetails object. This works but the age, is giving me problems and i will be happy to get help. There is the code:
I want the age, with similar validation rules: age can't contain letters and age should be between 16 - 120.
if its invalid, i want the while loop work till the users enters a valid age.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is this an academic exercise ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use separate `while` loops for each condition. Use a single loop that checks all the requirements of that input.

```js
let username;

while (true) {
  username = prompt("enter name please")
  if (!isNaN(username)) {
    alert("enter valid user name not numbers")
    continue;
  }
  if (username.length < 3 || username.length > 8) {
    alert("enter valid name pleas between 1 to 8")
    continue;
  }
  break;
}

console.log(username);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues.

If you are using condition1 and condition2 sequentially and input1 satisfied condition1 then in next iteration, it will only check with condition2.
So, you should check all conditions for all the inputs.
Second, we already have some validators in HTML form, why not use them?
I would write a validator in the document itself.

So, here is first solution which still uses while loop and prompt.
I have taken liberty of refactoring it a little bit.

```
  var userMessage = "";

  const isValidName = (username) => {
    let valid = username && username.length >= 3 && username.length <= 8 && /^[A-Za-z ]+$/.test(username);
    if(!valid) userMessage = "username should be 3 to 8 chars long and should only contains alphabets";
    return valid;
  }

  const isValidAge = (age) => {
    let valid = age && age >= 16 && age <= 120;
    if(!valid) userMessage = "Age should be between 16 & 120";
    return valid;
  }

  document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function () {
    let username = prompt("Enter Name. ")
    while (!isValidName(username)) {
      username = prompt("Enter Name. " + userMessage);
    }
    let age = prompt("enter your age ");
    while (!isValidAge(age)) {
      age = prompt("Enter your age. " + userMessage);
    }
    alert("Username: "+username + " Age: "+age);
  }
```

Now, for second solution, lets use form elements.

```
    <form>
        username: <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,8}" title="Min-length: 3; max-length: 8; Should contain only alphabets">
        age: <input type="number" max=120 min=16>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

This approach should be lot more convenient to use for any further step.
Unless you have a very specific scenario.